# LCD 20x4 Only Show Fist and Third Rows Pixels On

Tags: lcd, display

I have a LCD 20x4 display this display works fine but now it shows first and third rows all pixels On. I am using 4MHz crystal oscillator.

That is happen when Vss, Vdd, Vee, RS, RW, E, A and K pins supply without connect Data pins.

When these pins connected it should show all four rows pixels On right?

Why this happens?

After data pins connect also same things. I am using PIC18F4550 microcontroller. When I use PIC16F887 then it is working fine.

[image: LCD Display]

Same pins for both PIC16F887 and PIC18F4550. Protues simulation is working but real LCD not working for PIC18F4550

[image: Circuit]

```
 // LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at RD0_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RD1_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RD4_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RD5_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RD6_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RD7_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISD0_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISD1_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISD4_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISD5_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISD6_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISD7_bit;
// End LCD module connections

void main() {

  Lcd_Init();
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
  Lcd_Out(1,6,"Welcome !");
  Delay_ms(2000);
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);

  while(1){

  }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide full schematics of the circuit for each micro?

Comment: @mike65535 updated

Comment: I have seen this pattern before.  I think it is some sort of internal reset state.  It probably means you don't have something connected properly or you aren't implementing the protocol properly.

Comment: I think code configuration error. I am using 4MHz crystal oscillator. Also I did not configure internal oscillator. Please find out code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default state, only the first row is active. These displays can only have two logical lines, if there are more physical lines, they are either organized 2x40 logically or have multiple controllers for bigger screens.

Comment: Why this code not working ? Only show like above photo

Comment: First check if the contrast is too high. The code may be working but you can't see it because white and black pixels are the same for the active row.

Comment: I am using variable resistor for that. Do I need to set some setting in main function? Like internal oscillator? When I run this code protuse it is working

Comment: If you aren't sure if your µC is running, you should fix that first. It's another question then. Also, check if the libraries you are using are supporting 4-bit mode.

Comment: I have two uc both have same problem. It should be code error. I double check wiring.